# Two column (div) layout. Left: fixed and scrollable, text with headers, Right: float, image per header in left text

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-scrolling, custom-scrolling

To tell a story with some images I'd like to present the text on the left, scrollable and the right should ideally display an image per header.

I'm a beginner. I haven't tried that much yet. I know how to make the two column design, not how to connect images to headers/position in the scollable text..

```css
#content, html, body {
    height: 98%;
}
#left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

I'd hope to scroll through the text in the left column and automatically get corresponding images on the right...

Comment: Please share the related HTML and JavaScript (if any) and state the problem/issue/error you are facing with them.

Comment: Hi. I have something like:
http://benfrain.com/playground/scroll-test.html

What I'd like is that if I Scroll the text in the left column that the center column would auto scroll/update.
I'd put images in the center column to go with different sections of the text in the left column.

Comment: Although you should share your implementation of achieving this, but you can have a look at this question to get an idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378615/linked-horizontal-scrolling-with-two-divs

Comment: Here's a link to what I have so far:
http://mediviz.nl/tijdelijk/

Text left, images right. Now everything is scrollable. I'd like to hook/anchor the images to specific positions in the left text... Something like one image visible per chapter....